# Programmatically created controls not rendering

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

As I was required to sort of mask input in a textbox, I decided to construct my own control to handle this.

One of many templates could be "Size {enter size} Colour {enter colour}" which I've broken down to create a series of controls. The custom control that extends `StackPanel` which I've named `CustomTextBox` generates the following from the constructor.

```
// Pseudo
Children = {
    Label = { Content = "Size" },
    TextBox = { Text = "enter size" },
    Label = { Content = "Colour" },
    TextBox = { Text = "enter colour" }
    // .. and an arbitrary amount of more Labels and TextBoxes in no particular order
}
```

So far so good. But when I want it to render.. That's where my headache starts.
I've tried to add the controls to the `Children` property and `Measure/Arrange` on the parent, itself and all the `Children`. `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` do change to something other than `0`, but they won't render/display/become visible whatsoever.

I've also tried to use an `ItemsControl` and add the controls to the `ItemsSource` property to no avail.

I've tried to predefine sizes on everything, colour the background red and all, but the elusive controls remain to be caught and tied to my screen.

There's got to be a huge "Oooh..." here that I just can't find. I refuse to believe that this can't be done. I mean, it's WPF. WPF is awesome.

**Edit** Updated to what I currently have that seems most likely to work - still doesn't though.

Whatever I do in the designer shows up, but nothing I do in the `CustomTextBox` makes any visible difference.

**Edit**
New headline that fits the problem better.

Also, I've found several examples of programmatically adding controls. Take [this article](http://arcanecode.com/2007/09/07/adding-wpf-controls-progrrammatically/) for example. I fail to see the difference between my scenario and theirs, except that theirs work and the buttons are visible.

Comment: Is there any good reason not to create a simple UserControl?

Comment: @Clemens The best reason right now is that I can't think of a way to achieve what I want when the mask is arbitrary.

Comment: There is no need to override anything. Just add controls to a Panel, e.g. a top level horizontal StackPanel in a UserControl. It is also unclear which ItemsSource property you are talking about. Are you using an ItemsControl anywhere? Without seeing some code it is hard to tell where you went wrong.

Comment: @Heki ItemsSource property is for data, not for visual elements. You can create a usercontrol and drop your textboxes with labels on it and then handle the logic in code-behind. There is no need to implement custom control inherited from ItemsControl

Comment: @netaholic That doesn't explain the problem I have with a `StackPanel` though. But thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @netaholic Could I maybe get you to write some code up that illustrates your proposal btw? Perhaps it'll lead me in the right direction cause I'm still at square one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update3**

The mistake was to assume, that one can simply replace control in visual tree by assigning in codebehind a new control to it's name (specified in xaml)

**Updated2**

Your mistake was following. If you write

```
    <TextBlock Name="tb" Text="tb"/>
```

and then in code you will do

```
tb = new TextBlock() { Text = "Test" };
```

then you will have a new textblock as a variable, and nothing in xaml will change. You either have to change existing control, or remove old control and add new.

I'm talking about your Headline, Subtext & Description. You don't change them

**Updated:**

Here is an example of dynamically creating controls by specifying input mask:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication35.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication35">
    <Grid>
        <local:UserControl1 x:Name="myUserControl"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myUserControl.BuildControls("a {enter a} b {enter b1}{enter c2}");
        }
    }
```

UserControl1.xaml

```
  <UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication35.UserControl1"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="300">
        <WrapPanel Name="root" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </UserControl>
```

UserControl1.cs

```
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public List<CustomField> Fields = new List<CustomField>();
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public UserControl1(string mask)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BuildControls(mask);
        }

        public void BuildControls(string mask)
        {
            //Parsing Input
            var fields = Regex.Split(mask, @"(.*?\}\s)");
            foreach (var item in fields)
            {
                if (item != "")
                {
                    int index = item.IndexOf('{');
                    string namestring = item.Substring(0, index).Trim();
                    var field = new CustomField() { Name = namestring };

                    string valuesstring = item.Substring(index, item.Length - index).Trim();
                    var values = valuesstring.Split(new char[] { '{', '}' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    foreach (var val in values)
                    {
                        var valuewrapper = new FieldValue() { Value = val };
                        field.Values.Add(valuewrapper);
                    }
                    Fields.Add(field);
                }
            }

            foreach (var field in Fields)
            {
                var stackPanel = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
                var label = new Label() { Content = field.Name, Margin = new Thickness(4) };
                stackPanel.Children.Add(label);
                foreach (var item in field.Values)
                {
                    var tb = new TextBox() { Margin = new Thickness(4), Width = 200 };
                    tb.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("Value"), Source = item, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
                    stackPanel.Children.Add(tb);
                }
                root.Children.Add(stackPanel);
            }
        }


    }

    public class CustomField
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<FieldValue> Values = new List<FieldValue>();
    }
    public class FieldValue
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

This way fields and values are gonna be represented by Fields collection in UserControl1. Values of fields are updated as user types something. But only one-way, i.e. user input updates corresponding Value property, but changing Value property at runtime will not affect corresponding textbox. To implement updating from Value to textbox you have to implement INotifyProperty interface

---

*Obsolete*

Since you've asked.
There are hundreds of possible implementations, depending on what are you trying to archieve, how do you want validation to be, do you want to use MVVM, do you want to use bindings etc. There are generally 2 approaches : creating usercontrol and creating custom control. First one suits you better I believe.

Create a usercontrol with following xaml:

```
  <Grid Height="24">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Size: " Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBox Name="tbSize"  Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Content="Colour:"  Grid.Column="2"/>
        <TextBox Name="tbColour"  Grid.Column="3"/>
    </Grid>
```

In code-behind you can access TextBoxes by their name and do whatever you want to do.

You can use usercontrol in both xaml and codebehind.
In xaml:

Specify alias for namespace of your usercontrol (look at xmlns:local)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication35.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication35">
    <Grid>
        <local:UserControl1/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In codebehind you can use it like this:

```
 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var myUserControl = new UserControl1();
        }
```

There is a lot to say and these are basic things, so check tutorials and ask questions.

P.S. If you are learning WPF it's mandatory to learn bindings.

Comment: Well, it's all good, but it doesn't cover the dynamic part of the requirement. I can't know if I need just a label, just a textbox or seventeen pairs and two extra. It does show whatever I have in my `UserControl` but whatever controls I add programmatically doesn't show.

Comment: @Heki your requirement is unclear to me. Could you precisely describe what behaviour are you trying to archieve?

Comment: I'll update the question when we're on the same page. So, I need to be able to configure an input field based on some input, like "a {bla} b {bla} {bla}", but it could really be anything. I need to enable the users to only edit whatever's inside the { }. Makes sense?

Comment: @Heki, makes sence. Now I see why you wanted to use ItemsControl. I'll update my answer a bit later

Comment: @Heki did you find my answer helpfull? Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: I couldn't make it render so I tried binding to `DateTime.Now.Minute` and made absolutely sure that there's a number in the `Text` property, but it's just not rendering... It's driving me crazy. Again all the XAML renders but whatever I add programmatically just doesn't show. Argh!

Comment: @Heki share you project. There might be some silly mistake

Comment: @Heki check my answer

Comment: So you're saying I should make a dummy `TextBox` and a dummy `TextBlock` and copy them when I need more than one of each? I'm really grateful that you're going this much out of your way to help me, don't get me wrong.

Comment: @Heki i'm afk right now, but what I am saying is that you shouldn't re-createl Headine, Subtext & Description every time. Move all your code in CustomTextBox out of its constructor to one public method. Clear root's children at start of this method, to make it reusable, and call this method on Headine, Subtext & Description, instead of 'new CustomTextBox(){...'

Comment: Well that did the trick. So I can't do things in their own constructor the way I tried. Gotta, as you say, instanciate in the parent and do a seperate call to a public method. So thank you for your help, it solved my problem.

Comment: Your latest comment is what helped me though, so if you update your answer to reflect that, I'll accept it :)